# Simple form validation help "Cannot read property 'elements' of undefined"

Tags: javascript

newbie here, im trying to figure out  why i get "Cannot read property 'elements' of undefined ".

javascript:

```
function conf()
{
    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        box = document.project.elements[i];
        if (!box.value) 
        {
            alert('You haven\'t filled in ' + box.name + '!');
            return false
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

html:

```
<form id="project" onsubmit="return conf()" action="#"> 
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Contact Details</legend>
        <label for="txtname">Your Name:</label> <input type="text" class="text" name="txtname" id="1" /><br/>
        <label for="txtemail">Email:</label> <input type="text" class="text" name="txtemail" id="2"/><br/>
        <label for="txtartist">Artist:</label> <input type="text" class="text" name="txtartist" id="3"/><br/>
        <label for="txtalbum">Song / Album:</label> <input type="text" class="text" name="txtalbum" id="4"/><br/>
        <label for="txtcomments">Comments:</label> <textarea class="ta" name="txtcomments" id="txtcomments" cols="30" rows="20"></textarea><br/>
        <input type="submit" class="buttons" id="btnSubmit" name="btnsubmit" value="Send Enquiry"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: oh sorry, line 7 :
box = document.project.elements[i];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get at the form elements you need to use the form id,

```
document.getElementById('project').elements[i];
```

a better approach would be use the `document.querySelectorAll()` and get the elements you are interested in, which would be in this case,

```
document.querySelectorAll('#project input[type="text"], textarea')
```

which gives you an array of elements that you could loop through and perform the checks.

BTW, you will probably sooner or later start needing individual checks for each of the inputs. One approach to this would be use the new [HTML5 input types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input).

Comment: thank you, that did the job :D
this is slightly unrelated but, i notice it selects fieldset as the element, where i need it to select input. is there anyway to do this without removing fieldset?

Comment: to select only the `input type="text"` elements and the `textarea` you can use `document.querySelectorAll('#project input[type="text"], textarea')` and loop through that instead.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you have tried should work, since forms with an ID are made named properties of the *document* object. Perhaps you have another element with a name or id of *project*.

If the form is the only element with a name or ID of *project*, you write, formally:

```
document.forms.project.elements...
```

or shorter:

```
document.project.elements...
```

But that issue can be avoided. Since you have a submit listener on the form, you can pass a reference to the form directly by passing *this*:

```
<form id="project" onsubmit="return conf(this)" action="#">
```

And within the function (don't forget to declare variables!!):

```
function conf(form) 
{
    var box;

    for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
        box = form.elements[i];

        if (!box.value) {
            alert('You haven\'t filled in ' + box.name + '!');
            return false
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now you can change the form ID to anything (or remove it) and the function still works.

Also, the label element is associated with a form control by **ID**, not by name so:

```
<label for="txtalbum">Song / Album:</label> <input ... name="txtalbum" id="4">
```

should be:

```
<label for="4">Song / Album:</label> <input ... name="txtalbum" id="4">
```

Otherwise the label will not be associated with the element (and therefore may as well be a span or similar and not have a *for* attribute).

Lastly, please don't use XML syntax in an HTML document. In an HTML document, the `/` in `<br />` and `<input ... />` is simply ignored.